# DataTables TableTools not loaded in the page

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have following `JSs` and `CSSs` included in the page and loading OK in the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"/>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/js/jquery.dataTables.js"/>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/js/dataTables.tableTools.js"/>"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/css/dataTables.tableTools.css"/>">
```

Then I have following script to load `DataTables`

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#firstTable').DataTable({
    "dom": 'Tt',
    "ordering": false,
    "tableTools": {
        "sSwfPath": "<%= request.getContextPath() %>/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf" 
    }
  });   
} );
</script>
```

Everything is loading fine and normal `DataTables` initialization is also working fine I tested with plain

```
$('#firstTable').DataTable();
```

But `TableTools` is not loaded on page. I am not getting buttons on the page and I don't see `TableTools` component on the Firebug debug tool. Am I missing any config?

Comment: are you sure that `request.getContextPath()` is returning you the correct path? Make sure that `<%= request.getContextPath() %>/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf` exists

Comment: Do you have flash installed?, put in dom: 'T<"clear">lfrtip'

Comment: @Matei Mihai - Yes it is returing correct path

Comment: @ JuaRoAl - Same functionality working in other app in same machine. With dom config I have everything except T.

Comment: what if you use `${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}` ??

Comment: are you sure that the url : ` http : // ip : port / {app_name}/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf' returns the swf file for downloading it? (without the spaces of course)